# 404/CAPTCHA/Error images

Tags: discussion, design

Do you have any suggestions on what the images on 404, CAPTCHA and Error pages should be?

A few examples from other sites:

Cooking site's 404:

[image]

Gaming site's CAPTCHA

[image]

Photography site's 404

[image]

The idea is to have these images somewhat light hearted, and reflect the theme of the site. What are your suggestions for this site? You can just tell me the concept and I can implement it graphically.

Comment: Just to mention; this is still an avid issue!

Comment: I have used the 404/CAPTCHA images submitted. I still need one for the /error page.

Answer (score 14):

How about a scatter plot with a clear outlier, marked 404. Also this one could be used for captcha, with on the axes speed and reputation and than an outlier with a high speed.

Regrettably, I'm not having time now for a mockup.

EDIT: Drafts by mbq:
[image]

[image]

Comment: I like it......

Comment: @mbq Indeed, something like this! Thanks!

Comment: Cool!  I was thinking of something like this.  Perfect for the captcha.

Comment: @mbq The Captcha one is even better :) !!!!!

Comment: @mbq Ever since I came across the "Robot?" one in the wild, I've been wondering where it is from... by chance I found this post! Would you mind explaining how you generated it?

Comment: @Jim This is just some bunch of pseudo-random numbers, based on my naive guess how such robot detector could work. The "robot" point was actually manually drawn in Inkscape, IIRC.

Answer (score 5):

For the 404 page:

I don't have a pretty picture, but I have an idea: a standard normal distribution plot with everything < -4.04 shaded and -4.04 visible on the x-axis.  Then the words "You are here" with an arrow pointing to the shaded region.

Comment: Also a great idea.

Answer (score 4):

Or this:

[image]

Comment: This would be better if it were `return 404;`

Comment: ...but you would need to change the comment from `// chosen by fair dice roll` to something like `// chosen from random URL`

Comment: @Joshua Great ideas!

Answer (score 3):

We could take something from [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/423/what-is-your-favorite-data-analysis-cartoon), such as this one:

http://www.austinthirdgen.org/upload/piechart.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a NaN flow for error page? Like

```
  [1] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
 [19] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
 [37] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
 [55] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
 [73] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
 [91] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
[109] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
[127] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
[145] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
[163] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
[181] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
[199] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
[217] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
[235] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
[253] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
[271] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
[289] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
[307] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
[325] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
[343] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
[361] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Comment: That looks too much like a server error to me. And it's specific to R.

Comment: @onestop Very good, it is supposed to be a server error page ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Another 404 idea:

[image]